# implement a read operation list in debugfs

Tags: c, linux, kernel

i'm implementing a kernel module. using several techniques.
1 of them is to give read/write to different module variables.
i was able to read/write all variables except the list i have in my module.
the linked list:

```
    static struct node {
        struct list_head list;
        unsigned int x;
        struct tm time;
    };
```

i would like to have a corresponding file in debugfs that will print the full list.
i tried all the 'simple' read functions , but none of them actually work.. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can read list using function similar to this one:

```
struct k_list {                                                                 
        struct list_head links;                                                     
        int data;                                                                   
};                                                                              

struct k_list my_list;

static ssize_t pop_queue(struct file * file,                                       
                                char *buf,                                         
                                size_t count,                                      
                                loff_t *ppos)                                      
{                                                                                  
        struct list_head *pos, *q;                                                 
        struct k_list *tmp;                                                        

        printk(KERN_INFO "--Listing inserted numbers--");                          
        list_for_each_safe(pos, q, &my_list.links) {                               
                tmp = list_entry(pos, struct k_list, links);                       
                printk(KERN_INFO "object: %d ", tmp->data);                        
        }                                                                          
        printk(KERN_INFO "--End of list--");                                       

        return count;                                                              
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Linux kernel provides [seq_file](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/seq_file.txt) interface for easily implement files represented enumeration of things, like lists are.

All you need is to provide up to 4 functions which encapsulate enumeration:

```
// Assume this is the head of your list.
static struct my_list;

// Start iteration
static void *my_start (struct seq_file *m, loff_t *pos)
{
    // Use ready-made helper for lists.
    return seq_list_start(&my_list, *pos);
}

// Next iteration
static void * my_next(struct seq_file *m, void *v, loff_t *pos)
{
    // Use ready-made helper for lists.
    return seq_list_next(v, &my_list, pos);
}

// Output on single iteration
static int my_show (struct seq_file *m, void *v)
{
    // Get original structure
    struct node* node = list_entry(v, struct node, list);
    // E.g., print content of 'x' field
    seq_printf(m, "%u,", node->x);

    return 0; // Success
}

static struct seq_operations my_seq_ops = {
    .start = &my_start,
    .stop = NULL, // Not needed in this case
    .next = &my_next,
    .show = &my_show
};
```

Structure with these functions should be passed to `seq_open()` when opening the file:

```
static int my_open(struct inode* inode, struct file* filp)
{
    return seq_open(filp, &my_seq_ops);
}
```

And use `seq_read` as a `.read` function in file operations:

```
static struct file_operations my_file_ops = {
    .open = &my_open,
    .read = &seq_read,
};
```

---

Note, that *writing* into such file you should implement **manually**, `seq_lock` doesn't help with this.

Comment: thanks a lot :)  
i just tried it but i'm getting a kernel panic when trying to cat the debugfs file:
BUG: unable to handle kernel NULL pointer dereference at           (null)
i added include to the <linux/seq_file.h>. the assert comes right after it calls seq_printf.
thanks again!

Comment: Probably, your list is corrupted. Note, that in my code `static struct my_list;` is just a *declaration*, you should **initialize** that list and use it as a list of `node`s.